# How to write huge json file to dynamodb?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I want to write very large json file (>10GB) to dynamodb.
The json file consists of the following:

```
[
{"id": "000", "bar": 2, ... },
{"id": "001", "bar": 2, ... },
...
]
```

How to write this large file to dynamodb?

Comment: One way would be to use [AWS Data Pipeline](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-importexport-ddb.html).

Comment: Is each item in your array a new document in your table?

Comment: @Ani yes, every items have different primary id

Answer (score 1):

One way would be -

```
1. Store the file on AWS S3

2. Create an event on S3 when a new file is PUT

3. You will need a compute application which downloads the file and processes it, 
   now there are many fancy ways to do this, 
   based on how much you wish to spend on processing large files

4. Read each Object in your file array and send it to AWS SQS

5. Create a trigger on AWS SQS for an AWS Lambda function

6. The Lambda function can store your data on AWS DynamoDb, 
   make sure you have logic for failed puts, 
   as your file may or may not have duplicate ids, just to be sure.
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplistically speaking you just need to do a `PutItem` for each item in the array (use `BatchWrite` for better performance). There are a number of ways to accomplish this.

1. Run some code locally that works against your file and calls to DynamoDB. If this is a one time thing I'd probably take this approach.
2. Run the code in a lambda. If this is something you'll be doing often I'd take this approach. There are some things to consider here.
3. How do I trigger the lambda? I would suggest writing the file to S3 and adding an event to the S3 bucket that calls your lambda. That will allow you to automate the processing every time a new file is uploaded.
4. Handle really large files. 10GB is larger than lambda will be able to store in a temp file, but you can stream the data in and process it from the stream. This should be easy enough when the structure of the JSON is simple (the root is an array). If you happen to be in C# the Newtonsoft library (the standard JSON library) has streaming capabilities built in; I assume other libraries do as well.
5. Be aware of processing time. If you can't safely process the file in the 15 minute max for a lambda then you'll need to consider how you address this. Again, there are options, though the size of your file might limit those options (off the top of my head I can't think of how you would use Step Functions, for example).

There are, of course, many other options. I've just listed the two solutions that I would most likely consider.