# What is the most efficient way to get data from large JSON file into SQL Server?

Tags: python, json, sql-server, azure

I have a project that requires processing large amounts of sales data in JSON files that I would like query-able in SQL Server - the files are as large as 150GB.

My question is how do I go about getting this data in SQL Server to be queried and analysed in the most efficient manner and what resources should I look for in terms of tools and computing power? How long can each file take to be transformed/converted with 64GB RAM vs 128GB? Will it be quicker to use OPENJSON in SQL or use Python to convert JSON to CSV and then import into SQL Server?

I do have the template for data files and know the structure which has a couple nested arrays at most with 15-20 columns in total and millions of rows. There are hundreds of files and the data can go into hundreds of terabytes but what kind of compressions can I expect when converting from JSON to SQL Server?

Any insight or guidance is highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I suspect SQL Server isn't the best place to store this in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

look at this link if it gives some idea: [How to write huge json file to dynamodb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60629020/how-to-write-huge-json-file-to-dynamodb)

If I would have to do this task, I will prefer DynamoDB rather than SQL server ( SQL is rigid in its structure). The above link talks about upload the file to S3 and read S3 to push it to DB.

Another good read:https://medium.com/expedia-group-tech/how-to-upload-large-files-to-aws-s3-200549da5ec1